# MATLAB round values such that none are zero

Tags: matlab

I have an array of values and I am trying to round them all to integers, but I don't want any of them to become zeros.

Some of the values look like this:

```
0.00001
-0.03
-0.000001
0.789
1
```

I would like the result after the rounding to look like this:

```
1
-1
-1
1
1
```

I tried round(), ceil(), floor(), etc. but I'm not sure what to do in this case. Any advice?

Comment: Are all your values between -1 and 1, or is that just some example values?

Comment: Just some example values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `fix` allows you to round all numbers *towards* zero, there is no built-in to do the opposite. You could use `ceil` on the absolute value of the array to round each entry up to the next highest integer and then multiply by the `sign` of your data to apply the correct sign to the result.

```
result = sign(data) .* ceil(abs(data))

%    1
%   -1
%   -1
%    1
%    1
```

Comment: In my own personal MATLAB toolbox, I have an overloaded `round` function that includes the option "`break`" (opposite of fix) that does exactly this.